# Zerofill size overflow in OS X assembly

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, integer-overflow, bug-reporting

Suppose the following piece of C++ code:

```cc
char huge[0x900000000];
char large[0x90000000];
```

On OS X, this fails to compile (`g++ -c filename.cc`):

```
….s:4:zerofill size (2415919104.) <0! Ignored.
….s:4:Rest of line ignored. 1st junk character valued 44 (,).
```

Looking at the assembly code (`g++ -S filename.cc`):

```
    .section    __TEXT,__text,regular,pure_instructions
    .globl  _huge
.zerofill __DATA,__common,_huge,1,5
    .globl  _large
.zerofill __DATA,__common,_large,2415919104,5

.subsections_via_symbols
```

This was with the system gcc on Apple Mountain Lion, namely `i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-g++-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)`. I also have a version installed via MacPorts: `g++-mp-4.8 (MacPorts gcc48 4.8.2_0) 4.8.2`. With that I get essentially the same error message, although the generated assembly now looks like this:

```
    .globl _huge
    .zerofill __DATA,__pu_bss5,_huge,38654705664,5
    .globl _large
    .zerofill __DATA,__pu_bss5,_large,2415919104,5
    .constructor
    .destructor
    .align 1
    .subsections_via_symbols
```

All of this looks to me like at least one bug: apparently the assembler does interpret that size as a signed 32 bit quantity, without regard for overflow. I'm unsure where to report this problem, though: is this a GCC bug, to be reported using the GCC bug tracker? Or is it a bug in the Apple assembler, and I should try to report it against XCode or something like this? If so, how exactly? Or is this in fact LLVM software in use here, and I should report it there?

And how about the fact that the system `gcc` generates a wrong size in its assembly output? Since the MacPorts version handles that better, I'd assume that GCC devs have fixed this in the meantime, and Apple will likely pick that up eventually. Do you agree with this, or should I file a second report somewhere to address this issue as well?

Comment: I would suggest filing both bugs with Apple. Then, perhaps you should check the bug against the 4.2.1 upstream GCC before you file it with them. According to the [reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/Assembler/Assembler.pdf), numeric constants greater than 2,147,483,647 are unsupported by the OSX assembler.

Comment: Submitted Apple bug report #15977897 for this.

Answer (score 0):

Apple engineers reported to my bug report #15977897 in this fashion:

> llvm-gcc has been unsupported for a couple of years now. Please use clang.

Using clang does indeed work. At least there are no error messages, and the object file does seem to have a `__DATA` segment of the right size marked with the `S_ZEROFILL` flag. This I found using the [MachOView](http://sourceforge.net/projects/machoview/) tool. The assembly code clang generates looks sane as well: it has the correct sizes for both variables.